# Resolving Groovy Map class

Tags: grails, groovy

Anyone can explain why calling [:].class on a map return null while calling [:].getClass() return the expected result Map. See example below

1-

```
["test",[test:"test"],23].each {     
  println it.class 
}
class java.lang.String
null
class java.lang.Integer
```

2-

```
["test",[test:"test"],23].each {     
  println it.getClass()
}
class java.lang.String
class java.util.LinkedHashMap
class java.lang.Integer
```

Ken

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the answer

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1824

EDIT -- sure.  I think the semantics of a Map are such that if you have

```
def m = [one:1, two:2]
```

you are supposed to be able to access the entries in the map like

```
m.one
```

in other words, access into the map is like getting a property on the map object.  If

```
m.class
```

returned the class, it would break those semantics, because 'class' is not a key added to the map by the programmer.

Thats what I gather....