# Why in Groovy Map.class returns null?

Tags: groovy

I have a simple piece of code in Groovy:

```
ErrorInfoVO vo = new ErrorInfoVO();
Object obj1 = vo;
System.out.println(obj1.class.getName());
System.out.println(obj1.getClass().getName());

Map map = new HashMap()
Object obj2 = map
System.out.println(obj2.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(obj2.class.getName());
```

The output is:

```
com.vo.ErrorInfoVO
com.vo.ErrorInfoVO
java.util.HashMap
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException:
```

Why `obj2.class` is returning the null ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113525/resolving-groovy-map-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving Groovy Map class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113525/resolving-groovy-map-class)

Answer (score 7):

You get `NullPointerException` because

```
obj2.class
```

does not translate to

```
obj2.getClass()
```

but rather to

```
obj2.get("class")
```

This is because `obj2` in your case example is of type `Map` and you use property notation. It means that `obj2.class` returns a value associated with a key named `class`, and a key-value entry associated with such key does not exist in your map, so it returns `null`. Then you call a `getName()` method on and you get `NullPointerException`.

This use case is described in the Groovy documentation page [Working with collections, 2.2. Map property notation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_map_property_notation):

> **Note:** by design `map.foo` will always look for the key `foo` in the map. This means `foo.class` will return `null` on a map that doesn’t contain the class key. Should you really want to know the class, then you must use `getClass()`:
>
> ```
> def map = [name: 'Gromit', likes: 'cheese', id: 1234]
> assert map.class == null
> assert map.get('class') == null
> assert map.getClass() == LinkedHashMap // this is probably what you want
> ```